# Manipulate text with shell script

Tags: shell

I have in the following code excerpt "option rc local '?'" On several devices (where '0' = disabled and '1' = enabled), but I don't know the value on all devices, I would like some help to change this line for "option rclocal '1'" regardless of the existing la value.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tddSI.png)

When I know the value, I use the following command:

$RCLOCAL= "option rclocal '0'"     or
$RCLOCAL= "option rclocal '1'"

sed -i "s/option rclocal ''/$RCLOCAL/g" test

Comment: I can't make sense of your writing. Do you really have _option rc local_ with the space between _rc_ and _local_? If not, why do you want _to change_ an already present _option rclocal_ _'1'_ to the same _option rclocal '1'_ rather than changing only _option rclocal '0'_? Finally, your _following command_ only replaces _option rclocal ''_ where no _existing la value_ is in the quotes, and it replaces not always with '1', but with what _$RCLOCAL_ contains. You have to provide consistent input.and output.

Comment: @OtavioM : (1) Don't post screenshots to code, but include it verbatim in your question. (2) Format code lines in your question (by prepending them with 4 spaces) (3) Most of the code you are talking about does not look like POSIX shell code. For instance, what language is `$RCLOCAL= "option rclocal '0'`  supposed to be? It would be valid in Perl, where scalar variables start with the character `$`..